Download failed using browser.downloads.download() API in popup.js firefox addon
I have this function in popup.js in a firefox extension that should download a file generated in the code.
The download is initialized but then fail without any apparent error other than the file saying "download failed" in the download section of the browser.
I've tried it with an url from the internet and it works fine.
function download() {
  const blob = new Blob(["smssjsjssjsj"], { type: "text/plain" });

  // Create a URL for the Blob
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  // Initiate the file download using the downloads API

  browser.downloads.download(
    {
      url: "url",
      filename: `xxxa.txt`,
      saveAs: false,
    },
    (downloadId) => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        errmessage.innerText =
          "Download failed:" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
      }
    }
  );
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}


function download() {
  const blob = new Blob(["smssjsjssjsj"], { type: "text/plain" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  browser.downloads.download({
    url: url,
    filename: `xxxa.txt`,
    saveAs: false
  }, (downloadId) => {
    if (downloadId) {
      console.log(`Download initiated with ID: ${downloadId}`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }, 10000); // 10-second delay before revoking URL, adjust as necessary
    } else if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error("Download failed: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
  });
}

